# Apple Compression Library: identify the algorithm used to compress data

Tags: swift, compression

Apple has four compression algorithms in its [Compression library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/Compression).

How can I tell which algorithm was used to compress a given NSData instance? The compressed data should have a header of some kind, no?

**edit:** by extension, how do you know the size of compressed/decompressed data and thus the required buffer size?